# Getting "React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency" error for a state that doesn't need to be in the dependency array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, eslint

My eslint is complaining about `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`. I am not doing anything wrong here right, the function should only run if the `pathname` changes:

```
 const pathname = usePathname();

  useEffect(() => {
    setNavigation(
      navigation.map((item) => ({
        ...item,
        current:
          item.href.toLowerCase() === pathname?.substring(3).toLowerCase()
      }))
    );
  }, [pathname]);
```

Should I just disable the lint with `eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` on that function?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you assume that `navigation` shouldn't be in the dependency array? If it changes, your `useEffect()` would use a wrong version of it.

Comment: To always have the fresh value of `navigation` and yet run `useEffect` only when `pathname` changes, he could use a function updater, like said in the below answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eslint is yelling because the idea is to have in the dependency any variable defined outside of a `useEffect`, and that's used inside of it. So you always have their most recent values in the callback.

In your case, to always have the freshest value of `navigation` and yet run `useEffect` only when `pathname` changes, you could use a function updater:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  setNavigation((navigation) =>
    navigation.map((item) => ({
      ...item,
      current: item.href.toLowerCase() === pathname?.substring(3).toLowerCase(),
    }))
  );
}, [pathname]);
```

This way, you are not using `navigation` from the outside, but the one that React will give to the state setter, ensuring it's always a fresh value. So the linter will let you be.

Side note: often, disabling the lint is not a good idea, as it might lead to bugs.